# How to mock a function using rewirejs and chai-spies in order to test it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocking, chai

## tl;dr

I am trying to test an **express app** using **mocha**, **chai**, **chai-spies** and **rewire**.

In particular, what I am trying to do is to mock a function that exists in a module and use a chai spy instead.

## My set-up

I have a module called `db.js` which exports a `saveUser()` method

**db.js**

```
module.exports.saveUser = (user) => {
  // saves user to database
};
```

The db module is required by `app.js` module

**app.js**

```
const db = require('./db');

module.exports.handleSignUp = (email, password) => {
  // create user object
  let user = {
    email: email,
    password: password
  };
  // save user to database
  db.saveUser(user); // <-- I want want to mock this in my test !!
};
```

Finally in my test file `app.test.js` I have the following

**app.test.js**

```
const chai = require('chai')
  , spies = require('chai-spies')
  , rewire = require('rewire');

chai.use(spies);
const expect = chai.expect;

// Mock the db.saveUser method within app.js
let app = rewire('./app');
let dbMock = {
  saveUser: chai.spy()
};
app.__set__('db', dbMock);

// Perform the test
it('should call saveUser', () => {
  let email = 'someone@example.com'
    , password = '123456';

  // run the method we want to test
  app.handleSignUp(email, password);

  // assert that the spy is called
  expect(dbMock.saveUser).to.be.spy; // <--- this test passes
  expect(dbMock.saveUser).to.have.been.called(); // <--- this test fails
});
```

## My problem

My problem is that my test for ensuring that the spy is called by app.handleSignUp fails as follows

```
AssertionError: expected { Spy } to have been called at Context.it (spies/app.test.js:25:40)
```

I sense that I am doing something wrong but I am stuck at the moment. Any help is appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I figured out what the problem was. From [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) github page:

> Limitations
>
> Using const It's not possible to rewire const (see #79). This can
>   probably be solved with proxies someday but requires further research.

So, changing `const db = require('./db');` to `let db = require('./db');` in `app.js` made all test pass.

### A better solution

However, since changing all `const` declarations to `let` in order to test an application with spies is a cumbersome, the following approach seems to be better:

We can require our `db` module in `app.js` as a `const` as we did, but instead of creating the spy and overwriting the const variable:

```
let dbMock = {
  saveUser: chai.spy()
};
app.__set__('db', dbMock);
```

we may use `rewire`'s  **getter** method to import the `db` module in our `app.test.js` file, and then mock the `saveUser()` method using our spy (that is to  *mutate* one of the `const` variable's properties; since objects in JS are passed by reference, getting and mutating the `db` object within app.test.js module is also mutates the same object within app.js module)

```
const db = app.__get__('db');
db.saveUser = chai.spy()
```

Finally, we can expect that the mutated `db.saveUser` (i.e our spy) will be called

```
expect(db.saveUser).to.have.been.called();
```

To sum up, both the `db.js` and `app.js` will not be changed, but the test file should now looks like the following:

```
const chai = require('chai')
  , spies = require('chai-spies')
  , rewire = require('rewire');

chai.use(spies);
let expect = chai.expect;

// Fetch the app object
let app = rewire('./app');

// Use the getter to read the const db object and mutate its saveUser property
const db = app.__get__('db');
db.saveUser = chai.spy()

// Finally perform the test using the mocked 
it('should call saveUser', () => {
  let email = 'someone@example.com'
    , password = '123456';

  // run the method we want to test
  app.handleSignUp(email, password);

  expect(db.saveUser).to.have.been.called(); // <--- now passes!!!
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I was banging my head over this. Indeed the solution of changing the `const` declaration to `let` is not ideal, but the `__get__` solution works amazing!!!

Comment: The above code is not working with me, saying "TypeError: app.handleSignUp is not a function"